# c#, winforms. Корзина покупателя в winforms

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

Привет всем. Есть БД MS SQL справочник Товаров (цена, картинка и т.д.). Подскажите пожалуйста, какие инструменты можно использовать для создания Корзины покупателя в winforms (с изображениями), при условии, что товары будут добавляться.

Comment: Какой-нибудь grid и базу данных.

Answer (score 1):

Если нужен красивый внешний вид в WinForms, то можно поступить так:

- создаете контрол-карточку товара, с картинками, описаниями и т.д.
- из результата запроса к базе, заполняете контролы-карточки сведениями.
- складываете заполненные контролы-карточки, например, в `FlowLayoutPanel`.

Но вообще вариантов может быть много, равно как и для любой другой технологии, будь то WPF или Asp.NET, на вкус и цвет, что называется.